# What's the difference between EDI, AS2 and GS1 and how do they work together?

Tags: edi, x12, edifact

I'm learning about EDI and there are many acronyms and standards that seem to overlap.
What is the difference between EDI (and a EDI translator) and AS2 (which seem to be EDI over HTTP)? Then there is GS1, whith it's own subsets (GS1 EANCOM GS1 XML
GS1 UN/CEFACT XML) and EDIFACT.

Why would one use an EDI translator like BOTS together with an AS2 server ? Are they complementary?

Is there a map, a guide or explanation of how do all theese standars work together in the context of supply chain ? (i.e: a warehouse which ships to client's own warehouses or stores).

Thanks

Comment: A lot of what you're asking can be found via Google search, but there's also this resource:  http://www.edibasics.com/

Answer (score 2):

From Walmart Getting Started with EDI
Implementation Guide ( http://cdn.corporate.walmart.com/5d/8d/897b4bb84a95bb05214bf897cee3/edi-getting-started-guide.pdf )

1. What is EDI?

   a. Simply stated, EDI (Electronic Data Interchange) is the
   electronic exchange of business documents between suppliers and retailers.

   b. EDI is comprised of two components: translation and communication.
   i. During translation, a business document is changed—or “translated”—into
   a standardized EDI format.

   c. There are various EDI standards (or formats) that a company may use.
   i. Please view “How is EDI data formatted?” for more information about the
   EDI standards that we support.

   d. Once a business document is translated into an EDI format it is communicated—
   or electronically sent—to the intended recipient.

   e. There are several methods of EDI communications available, but the method
   utilized by Walmart and our suppliers is AS2.
2. What is EDIINT AS2?

   a. EDIINT (EDI over the Internet) is a set of communication protocols, introduced by
   the IETF (Internet Engineering Task Force) in 1995, used to securely transmit data
   over the Internet.

   i. Although EDIINT was initially designed to transport EDI data, it may also be
   used to transfer non-EDI data.

   b. One version of EDIINT is AS2 or Applicability Statement 2.

   i. The UCC (Uniform Code Council) has facilitated the development and
   interoperability testing of the AS2 standard.

   ii. AS2 supports EDI or other data file transmissions over the Internet using
   HTTP/HTTPS.

   c. AS2 is a specification about how to transport data, not how to validate or process
   the content of the data.

   d. AS2 specifies the means to connect, deliver and receive data in a secure and
   reliable way.

   e. AS2 is not an asynchronous or FTP solution; it is an Internet Protocol based solution
   that uses standard HTTP/HTTPS communications to transmit data.

   f. For more information on EDIINT AS2, or for a list of interoperable-tested AS2
   software providers, visit http://www.drummondgroup.com.
   Getting Started with EDI – Implementation Guide
   Last Modified On: 4/14/2014 Wal-Mart Confidential 5

   g. For additional information see the EDIINT FAQ’s within Retail Link™ on the ECommerce/EDI
   page.
3. How is EDI data formatted?

   a. The information is formatted using EDI standards.

   b. Walmart currently supports:

   i. ANSI X12 (American National Standards Institute)

   1. UCS (Uniform Communications Standards)
   2. VICS (Voluntary Inter-industry Commerce Standard)
      ii. EDIFACT (Electronic Data Interchange For Administration, Commerce and
      T+ransport)

   c. Walmart stays within the VICS and UCS guidelines for our major documents within
   the United States and Canada. EDIFACT is only used for suppliers outside of the
   U+S and Canada and those that will be directly importing merchandise for our
   company.